# Entity Framework Core - incorrect EntityState

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My application uses Entity Framework v7. The model consists of customers and orders. A `Customer` can have many `Orders`. An `Order` has a single `Customer`.

The folowing statement retrieves all orders that have status "Completed" and eagerly loads the associated customer with each order:

```
var orders = dbcontext.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Where(o => o.Status == "Completed")
```

This returns the expected list of orders. After then checking the contents of `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries`, I notice that it not only contains the retrieved orders and customers, but also all other orders belonging to those customers that were eagerly loaded in the above statement. i.e. including those orders that do not have "Completed" status. This is as expected, as `customer.Orders` should return all orders, not just completed orders.

However when checking the `EntityState` of these entries, although the "Completed" orders have `EntityState` set to `Unchanged` (again as expected), the other orders (i.e. those not having "Completed" status) have `EntityState` set to `Added`. Therefore, upon subsequently calling `dbContext.SaveChanges()`, EF attempts to INSERT these orders which results in an error. Why is the `EntityState` getting set to `Added` for these orders? I would expect it to be set to `Unchanged`.

**Update**

Here is a complete code sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
public void Test()
{
    var entriesCountBefore = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count();   
    var orders = dbcontext.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Where(o => o.Status == "Completed"); 
    var entriesCountAfter = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count(); 
    var entriesCountUnchangedAfter = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Unchanged).Count(); 
    var entriesCountAddedAfter = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).Count();
}`
```

The values of each of the variables upon stepping through this method are:

```
    entriesCountBefore - 0
    entriesCountAfter - 5  (consisting of 3 orders and 2 customers)
    entriesCountUnchangedAfter - 4 (consisting of 2 orders and 2 customers)
    entriesCountAddedAfter - 1 (consisting of 1 order. This is the only order whose status is not "Completed")
```

Comment: It's an intriguing problem but without more code to see what's going on I'm struggling to spot possible problems/solutions - could you post more code please?

Comment: @mark_h thanks for your response. I've updated my question to include a more detailed code sample.

Comment: I don't see how the results you are stating are possible. I get the 0 result, I get the 5 result (I'm assuming that of your 3 orders, 2 share the same customer and that your customer/order relationship is 1-to-many). Then you do nothing, edit nothing, change nothing, yet only 4 of your entries have an unchanged status? All should have an unchanged status, because you've changed nothing. Your added count of one should be 0 because you've added nothing. Is this literally the code you are using or have you edited it for the sake of the post?

Comment: enums > magic strings.

Comment: Please provide a full example showing the issue. I highly doubt the eager loading is causing the problem, however I do see problems lurking with the usage of an ambient DbContext (since ChangeTracking will then reward every single change of each object previously in the context with an according change in the EntityStates of its objects).